# Magento 2 check if product already in compare list

Tags: product, magento2.3, compare, product-listing

I want to check if products is already in compare list on product listing page and show remove compare button there

below is come of my list.phtml

**Add to compare**

```
<a  id="compareclick-<?php echo $product->getId();?>" href="#"
                               class="action compare"
                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('+ Compare')); ?>"
                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('+ Compare')); ?>"
                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                               role="button">
                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('+ Compare') ?></span>
                            </a>
```

**Remove from compare**

```
                        <a id="rxcompareclick-<?php echo $product->getId();?>" href="#"
                           class="action compare"
                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('+ Compare')); ?>"
                           aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('+ Compare')); ?>"
                           data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataRemove($_product); ?>'
                           role="button">
                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('+ Compare') ?></span>
                        </a>
```

I want to add condition so remove code should show If product in compare list

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`{theme_dir}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/compare/link.phtml`.

do this by calling the `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare` helper's method `hasItems()`

```
<?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
if ($compareHelper->hasItems()) { ?>
    //default Magento code
    <li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
        <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?php echo __('Compare Products') ?>"
           data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
        >
            <?php echo __('Compare Products') ?>
            (<span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>)
        </a>
    </li>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {"[data-role=compare-products-link]": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php echo $block->getJsLayout();?>}}
    </script>
    //end of default Magento code
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I want the same thing as asked. On the product list page (category page) standard it shows an "add to compare" button but when added to the compare list I want the "add to compare" button to be checked or replace it with an "remove from compare" button. In the module-catalog/helper/product/compare.php I also don't see the option of checking if product is added to the compare ..

Answer (score 0):

You may do it using Ko conditions

```
<li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
<!-- ko if: compareProducts().count -->
    <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?php echo __('Compare Products') ?>"
       data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
    >
        <?php echo __('Compare Products') ?>
        (<span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>)
    </a>
<!-- /ko -->
</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {"[data-role=compare-products-link]": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php echo $block->getJsLayout();?>}}
</script>
```